# VBA drop-down list IFS formula

Tags: excel, vba

This code is not working for me. Someone can see the error. It is shown Run Time error '1004'. The error it's on fomula 1 and this is not the full code but the error is specifically here.

```
Dim JT As String
    JT = Columns("E:E").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=IFS(L2=$M$2,B,L2=$N$2,Co,L2=$O$2,E,L2=$P$2,En,L2=$Q$2,I_T,L2=$R$2,O,L2=$S$2,P_B,L2=$T$2,Sp,L2=$U$2,SII)"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Comment: B, Co and the others are not the values I want, they are the name of the list of terms I want to be showned in the drop-down list

Comment: I think you'll need to put them in `"`'s so `,"co",`

Comment: Can you manually use that formula without error? (note that by selecting the whole of column E, row **1** is validating the value in row **2**, and so on down the column.)

Comment: I tried using " and "".

Comment: I can use this without error in excel, but for my application VBA is mandatory. I need to get the value in column L and depending which is the drop-down list is going to be different. I guess there may be better ways to solve this.

Comment: If you select the whole of column E, your formula should refer to row 1, not row 2.

Comment: But row1 are for headers

Comment: The formula is correct, the problem is format. There must be something wrong in the format of how I'm using the formula in VBA

Comment: Can I refere a column? Instead of L2 put L or something to refer the entire column in the formula?